# command line with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to do a command line like:

```
for /F "tokens=4" %%F in ('c:\spaces spaces\filever.exe /A /D D:\Spaces Other\a.dll') do (set VERSION=%%F)
```

I encounter a spaces problem.
How can I write that command with a paths with spaces.

Thanks, Ido

Comment: I edited you question, you can revert the changes if you don't like the changes or edit it again yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to put the path in quotes.

```
' "c:\spaces spaces\filever.exe" /A /D "D:\Spaces Other\a.dll" '
```